What does "quod" refer to in Vulgate in Matthew 26:75?
In Vulgate:

Et recordatus est Petrus verbi Jesu, quod dixerat : Priusquam gallus cantet, ter me negabis. Et egressus foras, flevit amare.
https://www.bible.com/bible/823/MAT.26.75

What does "quod" here refer to? If it refers to Jesus, it would be "qui", right? If it referred to the words that Jesus said, it would be "quae", right? So, what does it refer to?

The antecedent of quod is verbi, which here is genitive singular (not plural), same as ῥήματος in the Greek original.
In Greek, the object of μιμνήσκω (the original verb in the main sentence here) is in the genitive, as it sometimes is with meminisse, too. While recordor typically takes an accusative (and so does in most of Classical Latin), in later Latin and especially the Vulgate it can take a genitive, perhaps, I presume, by analogy with meminisse or μιμνήσκω.
That's what it's going on here. Note that genitive singular is the only case possible for verbi, as it's second declension neuter.
